# How to add row design in datatables depend on condition?

Tags: laravel, datatables

How to add row background color when item quantity counts reach less 5?

```
 .red 
 background-color: red !important;
```

My JS

```
 $(function() {
  var table = $('#item').DataTable({
    processing: false,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{!! route('admin.get.item') !!}',
    columns: [
        { data: 'item_quantity', name: 'item_quantity'
          if(item_quantity<5)
          $(row).css("background-color", "red");
        },
```

Table not showing is there an error on my condition?

Comment: You are mixing functions with table data, this will never work `{ data: 'item_quantity', name: 'item_quantity'
          if(item_quantity<5)
          $(row).css("background-color", "red");
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addClass,Try to add
$(row).css("background-color", "red");

Comment: problem is i think my js condition have wrong syntax because table not showing

Answer (score 0):

```
    { data: 'item_quantity',        
     render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
      if (type === 'display' && data <5) {
        var rowIndex = meta.row+1;
        $('#consumablestable tbody tr:nth-child('+rowIndex+')').addClass('lightRed');
        return data;
      } else {
        return data;
      }
    }},
```